# How to calculate difference in today avg sales vs yesterday avg sales in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I need to calculate the difference in today avg response time vs yesterday avg response time in tableau

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve]. You're wasting anyone's time who tries to answer this question if you're expecting people to guess what your data looks like.

Comment: Your question will be closed if it doesn't edited, as vague question won't be entertained in SO forum. Atleast post sample data and required output